# Spring two Transaction Managers, same datasource different implementation

Tags: spring

We are using Spring 3.0.5 with AOP for our transactions.

We have create an instance of WebLogicJtaTransactionManager and pointcuts on all the methods called under that service (like a SessionFacade...but these are non-ejb).

Later in the code, someone cut/pasted code from the Spring Batch Tutorial and created a JtaTransactionManager and pointcuts all the methods for the Repository class under that.

Would this cause a problem having two transaction managers that are different implementation classes (even though WebLogicJtaTransactionManager extends JtaTransactionManager)?

If the outer WebLogicJtaTransactionManager starts a REQUIRED transaction and then the JtaTransactionManager starts a REQUIRED, would they essentially be on the same transaction thread?

Comment: Most likely it will make a nested transaction. I'm a little iffy on JTA transactions as I think they use JNDI. Some people make their own transaction manager and use ThreadLocal so that they don't do a nested transaction but I don't recommend that.

Comment: @Adam - Thanks, that definitely would make sense.  In nested transactions...would the parent transaction then pause (with regards to timeout) until the nested child transaction was complete?  Or does the child transaction timeout when the parent does?